# Corrupted data when using LockBits/UnlockBits after saving and loading images

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, png

I'm writing a steganography program which supports multiple file types. There is a working implementation for WAV files and then one for image files, which is currently not working.

The image carrier is basically a wrapper around the .NET classes Bitmap and Image. It uses LockBits/UnlockBits to access the array of bytes contained in images. When the program is finished making changes to the byte array, it will copy it back into the Bitmap.

When the data has been copied and the Bitmap has been unlocked, I save it using:

```
image.Save(destination, ImageFormat.Png);
```

The next time I load the Image, I would expect that the byte array I saved earlier is identical to the one that I am going to extract from the saved Image (since PNG is lossless). However, this is not always the case.

The byte arrays are ALMOST identical, but SOME of the bytes with a value of 1 have been changed to 0. Other than this there is not really any pattern to it, seeing as it appears to happen to all channels.

Is there something about Image.Save or the PNG format that I have missed?

edit: When embedding the exact same data, it works for some images but not for all, even if they share the same attributes (both 24 bpp and PNG).

Comment: I know it looks counter-intuitive, but I wonder whether the image is still saved as a jpeg. If you open the file as a raw byte stream and look at the first few bytes for the header, what do you get? [JPEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format#File_format_structure) or [PNG](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Structure.html)?

Comment: The image appears to be saved as a PNG, which the header indicates.

Comment: The array you get from a LockBits operation is not compressed, it's raw pixels with a stride for alignment. Make sure your wrapper takes this into account
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.bitmapdata.stride%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I'm aware that the data is not compressed, but I have not given much thought to the stride. I've been treating the data as a pattern of bytes consisting of RGBRGBRGB.. (etc). Is that wrong? Note that I do not care about the order of the tuples, as long as I can expect that they are in this order

Comment: I should've done my research a bit more, turns out no data is lost, I'm just not implementing stride properly.

Answer (score 0):

When saving an image you can specify different compression algorithms. The default one might produce this undesired effect. Try another one.

See:
- [System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder Compression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.encoder.compression%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
-  [System.Drawing.Imaging.EncoderValue Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.encodervalue%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [Image.Save Method (String, ImageCodecInfo, EncoderParameters)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ytz20d80%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Don't confuse these compression algorithms with the image quality. Image quality should not affect PNGs, as they use lossless compression.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you can't specify this when saving as PNG.

Comment: You can always specify this. The question is whether the PNG codec takes it into account or not. Different compression algorithms result in different file sizes. So it should be easy to see whether it works or not. (**NOTE**: there are two overloads of the `Save` method).

Comment: That's true, it did not work however. Seems that these compression options only work with TIFF.